# Str_replace function special characters

Tags: php, arrays, function, str-replace

Is there any function or way to replace all characters at once?

```
$product['name'] = utf8_decode(strtolower( strip_tags( $child->name ) ) );
$product['name'] = str_replace(":", "-", $product['name']);
$product['name'] = str_replace("*", "", $product['name']);
$product['name'] = str_replace("#", "--", $product['name']);
$product['name'] = str_replace("@", "", $product['name']);
$product['name'] = str_replace("(", "---", $product['name']);
$product['name'] = str_replace(")", "", $product['name']);
etc
etc
```

Solution for me:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#95198

```
function strReplaceAssoc(array $replace, $product) {
   return str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $product);   
}
```

Comment: str_replace accepts array arguments, please check the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array... Pass those characters in an array as shown..

```
$product['name'] = str_replace(array(":",",","*"), "", $product['name']);
```

Comment: thnks, but how can i do it with array(
                "<i>" => '-',
                "<-i>" => '-',
                "&nbsp;" => '',
                "/" => '',
                "&amp;" => '',
                "/" => ''
                ) With str_replace_assoc?

Comment: @Bas, Sorry I was away when you sent me this message.. You got it solved?

Comment: yes see the post solution. I needed to replace key for value. See function. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
$replace = array(':','*','#','@',......);
$product['name'] = str_replace( $replace , "", $product['name'])
```

Comment: Please do not provide code-only answers. Explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$product['name'] = utf8_decode(strtolower( strip_tags( $child->name ) ) );
$blacklist=array(':','*','#','@','(',')');//etc etc
$product['name'] = str_replace( $blacklist , "", $product['name']);
```